# Sorting is not working in Primefaces datatable

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsf-2, primefaces

Sorting is not working in Primefaces datatable.My jsf code is shown.We need to do anything in backing bean to make it working?

```
<p:dataTable id="employees" value="#{employeeList.employees}"
     var="employee" emptyMessage="No Employees found" rows="10"
     paginator="true"
     paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink}  {PageLinks}      {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
     rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">

        <p:column sortBy="#{employee.firstName}">
           <f:facet name="header">
           <h:outputText value="First Name" />
           </f:facet>
           <h:outputText value="#{employee.firstName}">
           </h:outputText>
        </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="#{employee.lastName}">
           <f:facet name="header">
           <h:outputText value="Last Name" />
           </f:facet>
           <h:outputText value="#{employee.lastName}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

> My Primefaces version is 3.0.M3 with JSF2 and Google Cloud SQL

EmployeeList.java:

```
public List<Employee> getEmployees() throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        employees.addAll(empList());
}
```

Where in empList() I wrote query for retrieving all employees and which returns all employees.

**EmployeeList.java**

```
@Component("employeeList")
@SessionScoped
@Repository
public class newb implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2417394435764260084L;


    public static HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {       
        this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);     
    }

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() throws HibernateException, SQLException {

        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();       
        employees.addAll(empList());        
        return employees;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Employee> empList() {       
        try
        {           
            List <Employee> result =  hibernateTemplate.find("from Employee"); 
            return result;
        }
        finally { 
            //close the session and user-supplied JDBC connection 
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What happens if you try to click on the sorting button?

Comment: Is your `<p:dataTable>` tag is in `<h:form>` ?

Comment: On clicking the sorting arrow/column header, no effect on the information.

Comment: Yes, it is in `<h:form prependId="false">`.

Comment: I compile your code on GlassFish 3.1 with PrimeFaces 3.0.M3 and works fine.

Comment: if you will show the employeeList class it could help

Comment: Thanks! How is your backing bean going.Mine is like, `public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
 List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
  employees.addAll(empList());} `, in `empList()` I will retrieve all employees.

Comment: I have updated the issue above  with EmployeeList class.

Comment: What scope is your class of? and is it serializable?

Comment: it is serializable and is  @SessionScoped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
    if(employees.isEmpty()){
       employees.addAll(empList());
    }
    return employees;
}
```

Comment: It causes null pointer exception when `employees.addAll(empList());` is in the constructor.

Comment: ` Could not instantiate bean class [com.fetchinglife.application.modules.employee.view.EmployeeList]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Show your full EmployeeList class.

Comment: When I replace `List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();` from `getEmployees` to top as you said, then list items get duplicated and console shows program running continuously without stopping, later an error like,`cannot open connection`.

Comment: That is weird, because you invoke only once empList() when employees is empty.

Comment: Bur there is a problem.When I delete the data from the dataTable still it will there in the dataTable.But it will be deleted from the database.

Comment: Try to make EmployeeList RequestScoped.

Comment: No effect! i think this is due to the step `if(employees.isEmpty()){
       employees.addAll(empList());
    }`.When I logged out and re-login ,it is ok.

Comment: That is when it's SessionScoped, but if it's RequestScoped should change.

Comment: I have posted my issue as a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737768/issues-with-scope-jsf-primefaces

Answer (score 4):

It will not work if you have the list populated in your get. Sort it prime faces would not work if the list is populated each time in get. Instead try making the bean viewscoped and populate the list in the constructor, it should work then.

Comment: What if we are using CDI beans?